# how to add more than 100 varient of a product in shopify

Tags: shopify

I have 175 variant of product, but shopify shows the warning that you can not add more than 100 variants to a product.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's a restriction shopify does to its products. You won't be able to add more than 100 variants to *a single* product.

However, what are you trying to model? If there's not a change of price, for example, you're selling t-shirts and the color of the t-shirt doesn't really correlate to a change of price, you can model that using **line item properties**.

> You can collect customization information for products using line item properties. Line item properties let customers add information to a product when they add it to their cart. For example, you can let a customer specify text for a monogram or engraving on the product.

You can make your own dropdown that sets a line item with the value of the color, just to name an example. More information on the official tutorial [here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products).

If you do need 175 different prices, then you should split that on two products and set their template to a custom template where you manipulate things accordingly. Please notice, this could have a negative impact on SEO if not handled properly.